# Expandable and Collapsible folders

Tags: 2013, folder

Is there any way to make the folders in document libraries expandable? I.e. it reveals its contents when you click on it rather than taking you to another page wherein the folder is open? I can't use JS because it throws the XSS Audit error through chrome.

EDIT: It would be especially nice if there's a solution that allows more than just one layer of expandable folders. I.e. a folder inside of a folder will also expand and collapse.

Comment: Have you consider using tags (no folders) and creating a view based on tags and group them?

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply tags to documents. Wouldn't that restrict me to uploading a single document at a time?

Comment: No you can upload multiple documents and through quick edit apply tag on multiple documents

Comment: That's an interesting thought, but I don't think you can use that if you currently have a folder inside of a folder.

Comment: You can create a folderless view

Comment: What I mean is this will not allow multiple levels of expanding and collapsing. If an item is currently in Products > Cars, I cannot apply two tags both tags to it and have it collapsed under Cars when I expand Products.

Answer (score 2):

I think is not possible, but you have some workarounds:

**1) Tree view**

In Settings, Site Settings, Navigation Elements. This option is useful for folders navigations.

[image]

**2) Use the hidden button "Navigate Up"**

Useful too...

[image]

**3) Explorer view**

The more usable option for traditional users:

[image]